# Grab the filenames of the file from the directory and change as per string manipulation like String Concatination in BATCH script

Tags: string, file, batch-file, file-management

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "yourDir=D:\test"
set "yourExt=*.*"
set Name=ABCReport
set date=%date%
pushd %yourDir%
for %%a in (*.%yourExt%)  do (
  REM Do stuff with %%a here
  Set filename=%%a
  set NewFilename=%Name%_%filename:~4,8%
  REM echo !NewFilename:~4,8!
  echo !filename!
  echo !NewFilename!
)
popd
endlocal
```

I want to get the filenames from the directory and change the filename as per requirement.

By the above script I am getting !NewFilename! as below

> D:\test>"manipulate the filename.bat"
>
> data_20181222.xlsx
>
> ABCReport_~4,8

SO I want is `data_20181222.xlsx` file as `ABCReport_20181212`

Comment: Should `set "yourExt=*.*"` not be `set "yourExt=*"`? Also why not use the same syntax with all of your other `set` commands, i.e. `Set "variable=value"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `enabledelayedexpansion` but never use it?
I also assume you want to remove the characters of `filename` before you actually set the name with `ABCReport_..`

I've also set the `mydate` variable instead of manipulating the system variable `date`

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "yourDir=D:\"
set "yourExt=*.*"
set Name=ABCReport
set mydate=%date%
pushd %yourDir%
for %%a in (*.%yourExt%)  do (
  REM Do stuff with %%a here
  set "filename=%%a"
  set NewFilename=!filename:~4,8!
  set NewFilename=!name!_!NewFilename!
  REM echo !NewFilename:~4,8!
  echo !filename!
  echo !NewFilename!
 )
popd
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..Do you have a proper guide to work on the batch scripts..many things can be automated using these scripts when hav eto work on the windows platform

Comment: @Ajinkya yes. The best is to use the help functions. open `cmd` and type `help` which will bring a lot of commands, to see what each command can do, type the command followed by a `/?`switch. for instance `for /?` or `if /?` `setlocal /?` etc

Answer (score 0):

```
set NewFilename=%Name%_!filename:~4,8!
```

Since you are changing the value of `filename` within the loop, you need to use `!var!` to access the *changed* name.

Since `filename` has no value at the *start* of the loop, then `%filename:~4,8%` will become `~4,8` as you have observed.

BTW - it's legal, but considered bad practice to attempt to alter the values of pseudovariables like `date`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..Do you have a proper guide to work on the batch scripts..many things can be automated using these scripts when hav eto work on the windows platform